# How to give a custom object to an Angular component?

Tags: angular, object, parameter-passing

I have a little application that display counter, with the number of days between an event and the actual date. I made it for learning Angular.

I have a list of counters, and each counter can be seen, in the future with its own views, in a list. I want to delete a counter but for that task I need to give an object to a custom angular component. But when I try to retrieve it my component, it is undefined. Is Angular can only give primitive type ?

My counter model :

```js
    export class Counter {
      picture: string;
      synopsis: string;
      constructor(public title: string, public date: Date) {
      }
    }
```

I call my list of counter with that code :

```html
     <div *ngFor="let counter of counters">
        <app-display-test title="{{ counter.title }}" 
                          date="{{ counter.date }}"
                          counter="{{counter}}">
        </app-display-test>
    </div>
```

My display model :

```js
    export class DisplayTestComponent implements OnInit {

      @Input() title: string;
      @Input() date: Date;
      @Input() counter: Counter;

      constructor() {
       }

      ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.title);
        this.calculateCUrrentDate(); // my method for calculate the time
        console.log(this.counter);
        console.log(this.date);
      }
    }
```

In the ngOnInit method the tittle and the date have a value but the counter input is undefined, and I don't understand why

Comment: Can you post a reproduction using plunker?

Comment: Angular is not limited to primitive types. The reason why counter is undefined is somewhere else.

Comment: Unfortunately I won't have the time today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdfd6d?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

TS:

```
counters = []

constructor() {
   this.counters.push(new Counter("test",new Date))
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let counter of counters">
    <app-display-test [title]="counter.title" [date]="counter.date" [counter]="counter">
    </app-display-test>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used string interpolation to pass the object. Try this

```
<div *ngFor="let counter of counters">
    <app-display-test [title]="{{ counter.title }}" 
                      [date]="{{ counter.date }}"
                      [counter]="counter">
    </app-display-test>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that in angular hooks ( NgOnInit, AfterView, etc ) you don't know when input for dumb component is resolved.

So the best approach is to set it like this:

```
@Input() set(counter: Counter) {

if(!counter) {
return;
}

//do your logic here
this.calculateCUrrentDate(); // my method for calculate the time
console.log(counter);

}
```

The same applies for other inputs, therefore if you need to use that counter in html you would need to have local variable in that dumb component and call the change detection after you assign a value to it to be triggered for rendering in html.

PS: I would suggest you to use elvis operator from angular in html, e.g.

counter.somehting will crush your app if counter is undefined at some point.

So here for example you should use this and in whole app:

```
    <div *ngFor="let counter of counters">
    <app-display-test [title]="counter?.title" 
                      [date]="counter?.date"
                      [counter]="counter">
    </app-display-test>
</div>
```